# CSS list item weird positioning

Tags: html, css, list

I have this page here with an unorder list and list items:

https://artendijen.com/product-category/paintings/

towards the end of the page, there is a massive space where 2 list items should be, but are not. As you can see either from looking at the attached photo or looking at the site:

[image]

Here is my CSS for the list items:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
float: left;
margin: 0 3.8% 2.992em 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 230px;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

I have no idea why this is acting like this? any ideas?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the differing heights of the `li` elements.

Adding the following will solve this:

```
.products.animals > li {
    height: 310px;
}
```

Comment: @user1269625 This is the nature of floating elements. Since one of the last list items had a differing height of 2 lines: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9aWti.png .. it was pushing the others down.